# Chrome Zoom Causes Element Distortion

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm creating a simple radio button in CSS and am running into an issue where when you zoom in to 110% in Chrome, the positioning/size of the radio dot is distorted and no longer centered. This issue can be replicated with even simpler CSS, but it's most visible in this situation. When I inspect the dot at 110% zoom, Chrome sees it as 11.99px (instead of 12px like it's set) which could be part of the issue, but I'm unsure. In Safari, zooming doesn't cause any distortion issues. I looked around and couldn't find anyone talking about the specific issue, but it's so simple I can't help but wonder if it's a bug. Has anyone else seen this or have any workarounds?

Code:

```css
div {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

div::before {
  content: '';
  left: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Examples:
At 100%
[image]

At 110%
[image]

Comment: I think technically that border-radius only has to half the value of the width. Does that help at all if they're set to 8px and 6px? I'm on Firefox right now so can't test it. (Make a snippet out of your sample.)

Comment: Updated with a snippet. The border-radius is just there to show the use case, but without a border radius at all the alignment is still off.

Comment: Yeah, it's offset a bit on FF even at 100%. I think it's similar to the problem of `<hr />`s and the borders of table rows not all being the same width (there are questions here about that) but I'm not sure if there's an answer/fix. You might look for those questions for a tip.